# as3 Can StageWebView be tween or animated?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

Just wondering can you apply some animation on the StageWebView, for example slide in and slide out, i have apply with TweenLite.to() but i don't it accept StageWebView? Is it possible or i just have to be appear visible show and hide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's not possible. You can create the StageWebView, capture a snapshot of the contents and tween this snapshot into place, then once the tween has completed, replace the snapshot with the actual StageWebView.

The function required to do this is

```
drawViewPortToBitmapData(bitmap:BitmapData):void
```

Comment: Nice this is what i am after!!

Comment: Can you give a more detailed example?